# How to get the saved signature image in react-native-signature-capture

Tags: react-native

I'm just installing react-native-signature-capture but i can't find the image after saving ! however, the path is displayed (/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png') but i can't found anything neither the folder or the image ! then i want to upload the signature in firestore Storage , here is my code !!

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import SignatureCapture from "react-native-signature-capture";
import Orientation from "react-native-orientation";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import styles from "./styles";

class Signature extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
path: ""
};
this._onSaveEvent = this._onSaveEvent.bind(this);
this.saveSign = this.saveSign.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
Orientation.lockToLandscape();
}
_onDragEvent() {
// This callback will be called when the user enters signature
console.log("dragged");
}
_onSaveEvent(result) {
//result.encoded - for the base64 encoded png
//result.pathName - for the file path name
this.setState({ path: result.pathName });
console.log(this.state.path);
}
saveSign() {
this.sign.saveImage();
const imageRef = firebase
.storage()
.ref()
.child('P-APMTERM-LEHAV-FRAN-3/'+ new Date().toLocaleString+".png");
imageRef.putFile(this.state.path, { contentType: "image/png" }).on(
"state_changed",
snapshot => {
console.log(snapshot);
},
err => {
console.error(err);
},
uploadedFile => {
console.log(uploadedFile);
}
);
}

resetSign() {
this.sign.resetImage();
}
render() {
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
<Text style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
Signature Capture Extended{" "}

<SignatureCapture
style={[{ flex: 1 }, styles.signature]}
ref={input => (this.sign = input)}
onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
saveImageFileInExtStorage={false}
showNativeButtons={false}
showTitleLabel={false}
viewMode={"landscape"}
/>

    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.buttonStyle}
        onPress={() => {
          this.saveSign();
        }}
      >
        <Text>Save</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.buttonStyle}
        onPress={() => {
          this.resetSign();
        }}
      >
        <Text>Reset</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}

export default connect()(Signature);
```

i'm getting the path and the base64 but i can't find the image neither in emulator storage or in my android phone ?? then when uploading the signature in firebase storage i'm getting error of totalbytes -1 and status success ?

Answer (score 2):

### You have to set:

`saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}` in order for it to save in the camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

Use '`react-native-fetch-blob`' to place your picture file in the device folder.

There is currently a path, but there is no `function to download` the file or a `function to read` the file.
Use the readFile function if you want to read about the file right away.

```
readFile(path, encoding):Promise // path:string , encoding:string
```

> encoding: utf8 | base64 | ascii | uri

```js
import RNFetchBlob from "react-native-fetch-blob";
...
_onSaveEvent(result) {
//result.encoded - for the base64 encoded png
//result.pathName - for the file path name
RNFetchBlob.fs
    .writeFile(result.pathName, result.encoded, "encoding type")
    .then(success => {
      Alert.alert(
            "info",
            `It's been downloaded in ${result.pathName}.`
          );   })
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn(err)
    });
this.setState({ path: result.pathName });
console.log(this.state.path);
}
```

Description of the corresponding [module](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API)

Comment: You need to download the module. `yarn add react-native-fetch-blob`

Comment: i'm having in fact an a warning {"framesToPop":1,"nativeStackAndroid":[],"userInfo":null",code":EUNSPECIFIED"} and i can't found the image

Comment: Parameter data for a function may be incorrect or incorrectly encoded.

Comment: i didn't get it ? when i log the result i found the base64 and the pathfile and i put base64 as an encoded type !? so what is wrong ?
Ps: the function that shoud be used is readfile or writefile as your example ?

Comment: It is a matter of path https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/596#issuecomment-468329382

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `saveImageFileInExtStorage` variable to `true`:

```
saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}
```